# Difference between `net user /domain <username>` vs `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()`

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, active-directory, roles

Inside an MVC3 applciation I check `User.IsInRole(@"domain\groupname")` for myself and it returns `false`

If I call `System.Web.Security.Roles.GetRolesForUser()` I get 19 roles back, and the one I want to check is NOT amongst them.

If I open a cmd window and enter `net user /domain <username>` then I get back just 8 groups...but they are NOT the same as the ones from `GetRolesForUser()`  AND the role I want to check IS present???

(I have tried with both NTLM on/off) within Visual Studio.

I have no idea what's going on or why the two lists are so different?